# Using histogram in ArcGIS 10 with dates and sum of values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, graph, histogram

I have a point feature layer in ArcGIS. I want to add a histogram which shows a histogram for selected points. This works perfectly. Two problems:

- I have a datefield, which spans about three years. I would like the histogram to show totals by month and year. I bypassed the lack of option to do this by calculating year+month/12-1/12. It works, but it's hardly elegant. Also, the X-axis is dynamic, which I don't want. I would like the x-axis to show the whole period, not just months with observations
- I want the graph to show the total for the values in an attribute for the selected features. With a bar graph this seems to work, but it behaves erraticaly.

I cannot imagine no-one has done something like this before, but searching Google did not help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've done this. I sum the attribute value based on the date (I can't remember if it's better to have the date as a string variable or a date) and then do a histogram on the summation .dbf data.